# Sonatype Nexus 3 - Logging URLs proxy requests

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I'm trying to debug an issue of a proxy repository giving me a 404 for an artifact that I know exists in the repository being proxied (this is an NPM package in my case).

I would like to enable logging so that I can see the URL that Nexus is attempting to reach in responding to that proxy request but cannot seem to find any of the default loggers that provide this output.

What logger do I need to set and at what level to see this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you switch org.apache.http.wire to DEBUG, you will get a plethora of information on what calls are being made, almost too much information. This will give you information such as the following:

[image: Example output from org.apache.http.wire]

This was generated by switching that value and then doing a `install.packages("xts", repos="http://localhost:8081/repository/r-proxy")` from R Studio, against an R Proxy repo of CRAN.

Answer (score 0):

Note: im adding this answer to further flesh out the current one (I cannot comment). I was not able to find the debug logs in any log files on the nexus server and the current answer does not elaborate on this.

You can view any console logs you enable in the Nexus3 web interface.
Log into your nexus 3 server web interface and go to "Server administration and configuration" -> "Support" -> "Logging"

In your cased you want to do as the other answer outlines, turn on org.apache.http.wire logging, set this to "Debug".

Navigate to "Log Viewer" to see the output generated.

This is current as of:
version 3.38.1-01
edition OSS