# In Sonatype Nexus Docker proxy, how do I debug "Bad request" error?

Tags: docker, nexus, nexus3

I've been following the instructions to set up a [Proxy Repository for Docker](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/docker-registry/proxy-repository-for-docker). I am intending to set up a proxy for Docker hub, that is for https://index.docker.io/.

## My setup details on Nexus

- Nexus version 3.36.0-01
- Installed via `docker-compose`
- Generated/installed self-signed cert
- Using built-in https/jetty, *NOT* reverse proxy
- http listening on port 80
- https listening on port 443

## My setup details on Nexus docker proxy repo

- Configured for https, port 8443
- Proxy remote storage: https://registry-1.docker.io
- Proxy docker index: "use docker hub", pre-filled as https://index.docker.io/
- Allowing anonymous docker pull
- Enabled Docker Bearer Token Realm
- Enabled docker v1 API
- Enabled foreign layer caching

## My setup details on Ubuntu docker client

- Trusted self-signed cert in `/etc/docker/certs.d`
- Trusted self-signed cert in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` + `update-ca-certificates`
- Enabled Docker daemon debugging in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`
- Enabled Docker proxy via `httpsProxy` in `/home/myuser/.docker/config.json`
- Enabled Docker proxy via `httpsProxy` in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf`, reloaded/restarted Docker daemon

## My test from the client

- `docker pull hello-world:latest`
- returns error `Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Bad Request`
- In debug logs:

```
Nov 17 22:53:17 myclient dockerd[20160]: time="2021-11-17T22:53:17.190545462Z" level=debug msg="Calling HEAD /_ping"
Nov 17 22:53:17 myclient dockerd[20160]: time="2021-11-17T22:53:17.190878019Z" level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.40/info"
Nov 17 22:53:17 myclient dockerd[20160]: time="2021-11-17T22:53:17.213218413Z" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.40/images/create?fromImage=hello-world&tag=latest"
Nov 17 22:53:17 myclient dockerd[20160]: time="2021-11-17T22:53:17.213290250Z" level=debug msg="Trying to pull hello-world from https://registry-1.docker.io v2"
Nov 17 22:53:17 myclient dockerd[20160]: time="2021-11-17T22:53:17.234803592Z" level=warning msg="Error getting v2 registry: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Bad Request"
Nov 17 22:53:17 myclient dockerd[20160]: time="2021-11-17T22:53:17.234865780Z" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Bad Request"
Nov 17 22:53:17 myclient dockerd[20160]: time="2021-11-17T22:53:17.234976364Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.40/images/create returned error: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Bad Request"
```

## Next Steps

I'm watching the logs on the server while this is happening. It shows no errors. However the client side seems to indicate the request is partly working.

I tried increasing org.apache.http.wire to DEBUG as per [this other SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45723620/1090611), but that also showed nothing.

How do I continue debugging?

Answer (score 2):

If you examine the docker output you’ll notice it isn’t going to nexus, it is making the request to https://registry-1.docker.io.  To pull from Nexus you need to prepend the host and port to the pull request.

```
docker pull hostname:8443/hello-world:latest
```

There isn’t any way in docker to have it default to a private registry btw, so you’ll always need to prepend host:port.

Comment: Are you describing a "[hosted repository](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/docker-registry/hosted-repository-for-docker-%28private-registry-for-docker%29)"? That would be a different approach than the "[proxy repository](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/docker-registry/proxy-repository-for-docker)", which is what I'm attempting above.

Comment: Pretty sure he's saying that "Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Bad Request" is not pointing at Nexus Repository.  If it was it'd have https://localhost:8081/v2: Bad Request" for fake example.  See https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/docker-registry/pulling-images.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I updated the question to note specifically that I am attempting with `httpsProxy`. When that is enabled, everything breaks. So am I understanding  correctly that Docker's `httpsProxy` setting can not be used with Nexus Docker proxy repositories?